# Ball joint on robot

Tags: rigging

so i did this robot moddel in blender and i wanted to give it ball joints to move around, but ran into a problem when rigging. The mesh moves with the bone and makes it being out of place so i wonder if there is a way to make the ball rotate while being in the same place.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just put the head of the bone (in edit mode) exactly in the center of the sphere.

Then unparent the mesh from the armature and reparent it using this procedure: select the mesh, shift select the armature, Ctrl P "with empty groups". Then select all vertices of the arm, select the relevant vertex group and click the assign button under the vertex group tab.

This procedure avoid the problem that occours with automatic weighting, where the arm vertices would be partially influenced also by the others bones, deforming your mesh in unwanted ways.